# get and set local storage in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension I am trying to set and get local storage like:

```
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        'aa': 'bb'
    }, function () {
        console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
    });

    chrome.storage.sync.get({
        name: 'aa'
    }, function (result) {
        console.log('Value currently key ' + result.key + ', val ' + result.value + ', name ' + result.name);
    });
```

but `result` is undefined

EDIT:

---

how can I make it more flexible? I tried like:

```
    var key = 'aa';
    var value = 'bb';

    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        key: value
    }, function () {
        console.log('Value is set to bg' + value);
    });

    chrome.storage.sync.get(key, r => {
        console.log(r.key)
    })
```

Comment: chrome.storage.sync.get('aa', r => { console.log(r.aa) })

Comment: @wOxxOm Please see my update

Comment: See [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2274242)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @wOxxOm, the following worked for me:

```
    var key = 'aa';
    var value = 'bb';

    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        [key]: value
    }, function () {
        console.log('Value is set to bg ' + value);
    });

    chrome.storage.sync.get(key, r => {
        console.log(r[key]);
    })
```